Cannot launch Spyder in Anaconda Navigator and no error information returns on Mac
When launching Spyder from Anaconda Navigator, the application icon appears in the Mac dock and shows Application not responding, but no more error information comes out.
(https://i.sstatic.net/HlxD7rFO.png)
When launching in the Terminal, it returns error like:
(https://i.sstatic.net/DdDCsbn4.png)
I have uninstall and install both Spyder and Anaconda several times, but nothing changed...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I had a similar problem. Nothing worked until I typed in the conda prompt :
spyder --reset

